# Wanted: stories about shaatnez

Tags: halacha, agada-stories-legends, shaatnez

My daughter has a school project about shaatnez.  One of the requirements is to tell a few stories demonstrating how people were particularly careful about the laws of shaatnez, preferably with sources.  They can be classic or contemporary.  Any contributions will be most appreciated!

Comment: I feel  like some close reason must apply here, but can't figure out which.

Comment: @double aa, how's about off-topic because we don't do other people's homework for them?

Comment: @SethJ I was not aware we had a homework policy (though many SE sites do). Feel free to discuss enacting one over on [meta].

Comment: @double aa, I recall someone asking a question looking for info for a chaburah he was going to teach, and I am pretty sure we closed it.

Comment: Here are two stories http://matzav.com/shatnez-as-a-segulah-to-have-children-two-stories

Comment: @DoubleAA "too broad: There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format." No?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because we should not do homeworks for someone who can use google

Comment: @sabbahillel: No problem; my daughter finished her homework 4 years ago.

Comment: Sorry. i did not notice the date on the post.

Answer (score 13):

The story is told about the Steipler zt"l who at his first shidduch meeting with the sister of the Chazon Ish promptly fell asleep. When the Chazon Ish asked him to explain his behaviour, the Steipler answered that he had stayed awake the night before learning, figuring that could he sleep on the long train ride to the meeting the next day. But when he entered the train he saw that the seats were covered with a soft material and he was concerned that it might contain shaatnez, and so he stood for the whole journey. Thus he arrived at the meeting exhausted and so quickly fell asleep!